# Show map in fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, fancybox, mapbox

I have `fancybox` in my view.

When I open it, I have to show map on it.

Here is div for fancybox

```
<div id="markers_map" style="display:none">
  <div id="map_screen">
    <div class="clear"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And I  open it and try to show map like this:

```
$('#b_google_map_table').on("click", function() {
  $.fancybox.open($("#markers_map"), {
    width: 800,
    height: 500
  });
  mapboxgl.accessToken = token;
  let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'markers_map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-96, 37.8],
    zoom: 14
  });
});
```

It opens fancybox, but  unable to load  map. What is my problem?

**UPDATE**

I tried to rewrite it like this

```
$("#b_google_map_table").on("click", function(){
  $.fancybox.open($("#markers_map"), { width: 800,height:500, afterShow(){
    mapboxgl.accessToken = token;
    let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
          container: "map_screen",
          style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9",
          center: [-96, 37.8],
          zoom: 14
    });
  }, 
});
});
```

But it still not showing map in fancybox

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to use `afterShow` callback, see samples here http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#events

Something like this:

```
$('#b_google_map_table').on("click", function() {

  $.fancybox.open(
    src: "#markers_map",
    type: 'inline', 
    afterShow : function() {

      mapboxgl.accessToken = token;
      let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'markers_map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
        center: [-96, 37.8],
        zoom: 14
      });

    }
  });

});
```